# Unable to group by date in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to group my results by due_date in Oracle. But I keep getting the error `not a GROUP BY expression`.

```
SELECT S.* FROM Shipments S
WHERE S.delivered = 'false' 
AND S.customer_id = 'mycustomerid'
AND S.due_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-06-14','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2019-06-18','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY TO_DATE(S.due_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: this TO_DATE(S.due_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') should be in your SELECT clause...followed by the rest would be aggregation functions on other associated columns...for example...a sum of the orders by date...GROUP BY doesnt really make sense on a SELECT *

Comment: @Ctznkane525 `SELECT S.*, TO_DATE(S. due_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` ? If so I get the same error

Comment: Without the `s.*`. It'd be helpful if you show what your data looks like, and what you're expecting your outcome to be. What do you mean when you say "group my results"?

Comment: Aside from using `select *`, note that `group by function (date)` will be always slow. Use just `group by date` instead.

Comment: Let me guess you used to work with MySQL, before going Oracle database.. In MySQL where sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is non active the `SELECT S.* ... GROUP BY column/expression` might be  "valid" at the costs of possible invalid results or the query valid by SQL 99+ standards feature which is called functional dependency which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports

Comment: @AntarrByrd . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` basically never make sense together.  In an aggregation query, you have the columns (or expressions) in the `GROUP BY`.  *Everything else* should be the argument to an aggregation function.

So, if you wanted counts by day, you would do:

```
SELECT TRUNC(S.due_date), COUNT(*)
FROM Shipments S
WHERE S.delivered = 'false' AND
      S.customer_id = 'mycustomerid' AND
      S.due_date >= DATE '2019-06-14' AND
      S.due_date < DATE '2019-06-19'
GROUP BY TRUNC(S.due_date)
ORDER BY TRUNC(S.due_date);
```

Notes:

- `due_date` is -- presumably -- a date.  You don't need to convert a date to a date.  To remove the time component, use `trunc()`.
- Date comparisons shoud not use `between`.  Time components can interfere with such logic.  The above logic works for dates both with and without time components.
- Date constants can be introduced with the `date` keyword and use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: This works for getting the date and the count. but when I add another column it fails.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is an aggregation query which is required to use the aggregation functions `AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM` in columns to get the expected results:

```
SELECT TRUNC(S.due_date)
       ,COUNT(*)
       ,MAX(S.total_amount)
FROM Shipments S
WHERE S.delivered = 'false' AND
      S.customer_id = 'mycustomerid' AND
      S.due_date >= DATE '2019-06-14' AND
      S.due_date < DATE '2019-06-19'
GROUP BY TRUNC(S.due_date);
```

Assuming that `total_amount` is a column of `Shipments` table.